# AlarmManager inexact repeating alarm never fires (Xamarin android)

Tags: android, xamarin

The receiver's onReceive never runs

*adb shell dumpsys alarm* reveals the alarm is not set

Code setting the alarm (this code DOES run):

```
        Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(UpdateTask));
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, i, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        alarmMgr.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup,
            SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime(),
            60 * 1000, pi);
```

The BroadcastReceiver that should be started is defined like this:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
class UpdateTask : BroadcastReceiver {
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        [...]
```

Comment: I wouldn't think this would necessarily cause the alarm set to fail entirely, but you're setting a real-time alarm (`RtcWakeup`), but passing an elapsed time for the start time (`SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime()`). Additionally, `UpdateTask` is a `BroadcastReceiver`, but you're using a `PendingIntent` that starts a `Service` (`PendingIntent.GetService()`).

Comment: That was it! Changing to GetBroadcast solved it